# How to get individual items from tweepy stream

Tags: python, tweepy

I can't seem to get individual items i.e. getting just the text or just the user.

I've tried to use it as a dictionary or list but nothing seems to work. I don't, however, know how trustworthy my testing is as I'm an amateur.

```
def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            print(data.text(?))
            with open(self.fetched_tweets_filename, 'a') as tf:
                tf.write(data)
            return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print("Error on_data %s" % str(e))
        return True
```

I want "Sample tweet" however I'm getting various can't be parsed errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `on_data` method of StreamListener receives raw data as a string.
You can use [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) to deserialize the JSON to a dictionary to access the "text" key.
See https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/29bae1fde3ae0636fa13e5ed69f68f2af75c110b/tweepy/streaming.py#L42-L48.

Alternatively, you can use `on_status` instead to obtain a Status object, which has the `text` attribute.